# UnicodeDecodeError:TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Tags: python

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte Oxef in position 3: invalid continuation byte

When I added encoding="utf-8" to my code it got an error: I am using python version 3.9
**`File "<string>", line 16, in <module> TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'`**
I have a list with text files inside when I change the text inside with python it shows this error how can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
import fileinput
import os
import sys
FILENAME= []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'.' , topdown = False):
    for filename in files:
        if (filename.endswith('.xml')):
            FILENAME.append(filename)
            print(filename)
codeskin = input('Enter Code:')
Prefab = 'prefab_skill_effects/hero_skill_effects/'
codeskinmod = 'prefab_skill_effects/hero_skill_effects/'
Word = Prefab + codeskin
CarNew = input('Enter the Character To Replace:')
CarNews = codeskinmod + CarNew
with fileinput.FileInput(FILENAME , inplace = True ,backup = '.bak' , encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(Word, CarNews), end='')
file.close ()
```

Comment: This is difficult to reproduce, please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) next time. By the look of it you might need to add an `encoding` parameter in `with fileinput.FileInput(FILENAME, inplace=True ,backup = '.bak', encoding = "utf-8") as file:`

Comment: I tried it but the result is TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Comment: In that case please update your post to a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the error log message and the version of Python you are using.